# Modifying windows tracert output

Tags: windows, shell

`traceroute/tracert` is a great tool. However during troubleshooting, most of users only provided `traceroute/tracert` output. There is no way we can identify the actual source ip if it's not provided by user.

Therefore, I've come with an idea to put an source ip address in the traceroute tool. This can be easily be done with shell script, however I'm not sure how to do it on Windows.

E.g. on Linux

Traditional `traceroute` output

```
[user@linux ~]$ traceroute 10.1.1.6
traceroute to 10.1.1.6 (10.1.1.6), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.1.1.2 (10.1.1.2)  0.316 ms  0.442 ms  0.561 ms
 2  10.1.1.3 (10.1.1.3)  0.600 ms  0.700 ms  0.800 ms
 3  10.1.1.4 (10.1.1.4)  7.064 ms  7.209 ms  7.300 ms
 4  10.1.1.5 (10.1.1.5)  7.091 ms  7.216 ms  7.311 ms
 5  10.1.1.6 (10.1.1.6)  6.788 ms  6.788 ms  6.781 ms
[user@linux ~]$
```

To make it better, I've added date & source address.

```
[user@linux ~]$ test.sh 10.1.1.6   

 Date           : Thu Mar  8 12:08:42 +08 2018
 Source         : 10.1.1.1
 Destination    : 10.1.1.6

traceroute to 10.1.1.6 (10.1.1.6), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.1.1.2 (10.1.1.2)  0.332 ms  0.454 ms  0.562 ms
 2  10.1.1.3 (10.1.1.3)  0.591 ms  0.692 ms  0.786 ms
 3  10.1.1.4 (10.1.1.4)  7.059 ms  7.152 ms  7.266 ms
 4  10.1.1.5 (10.1.1.5)  7.068 ms  7.182 ms  7.252 ms
 5  10.1.1.6 (10.1.1.6)  6.803 ms  6.875 ms  6.875 ms

 ... Done ... 

[user@linux ~]$
```

This is the source in Linux

```
[user@linux ~]$ cat test.sh 
DATE=$(date +%Y.%m%d.%H%m)
echo -e "\n Date\t\t: $(date)"
echo -e " Source\t\t: $(ifconfig | grep ad | awk '{ print $2}')"
echo -e " Destination\t: $1\n"

traceroute $1
echo -e "\n ... Done ... \n"
[user@linux ~]$
```

Please let me know how to accomplish the same thing in window utilizing existing `tracert` tool.

Traditional `tracert`

```
C:\>tracert 10.1.1.5

Tracing route to 10.1.1.5 over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    15 ms    15 ms    15 ms  10.1.1.2
  2   166 ms    17 ms   303 ms  10.1.1.3
  3    16 ms    15 ms    15 ms  10.1.1.4
  4    16 ms    15 ms    15 ms  10.1.1.5

Trace complete.

C:\>
```

This is what I want

```
C:\>tracert-script.exe 10.1.1.5

 Date           : Thu Mar  8 12:08:42 +08 2018
 Source         : 10.1.1.1
 Destination    : 10.1.1.6

Tracing route to 10.1.1.5 over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    15 ms    15 ms    15 ms  10.1.1.2
  2   166 ms    17 ms   303 ms  10.1.1.3
  3    16 ms    15 ms    15 ms  10.1.1.4
  4    16 ms    15 ms    15 ms  10.1.1.5

Trace complete.

C:\>
```

Comment: `ipconfig` is the windows tool similar to `ifconfig` in linux

Comment: I know. But how to write similar script in windows?

Comment: http://steve-jansen.github.io/guides/windows-batch-scripting/